# Concurrent touches not being detected

Tags: java, andengine, touch

I have pretty much the same controls on the race example of the engine. A `AnalogOnScreenControl` and a button defined by a `Sprite`.

The problem is, when I'm using the analog directional, touching the button does not trigger `onAreaTouched` on the button sprite.

I even tried adding the button to the child scene (controller scene) but it doesn't register the secondary touch on the button.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

**UPDATE**

I am doing some debugging and apparently if I touch the control base, it triggers it's `onAreaTouched`, and if I keep touching the controls and then touch the button (on the other side of the screen) the same `onAreaTouched` from the control base is triggered. He's the only one receiving the touch event.

I really can't understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the stupid engine option missing. When creating the `EngineOptions` you have to add this:

```
final EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), this.mCamera);

engineOptions.getTouchOptions().setNeedsMultiTouch(true);

if(MultiTouch.isSupported(this)) {
    if(MultiTouch.isSupportedDistinct(this)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "MultiTouch detected --> Both controls will work properly!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "MultiTouch detected, but your device has problems distinguishing between fingers.\n\nControls are placed at different vertical locations.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry your device does NOT support MultiTouch!\n\n(Falling back to SingleTouch.)\n\nControls are placed at different vertical locations.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();     
}
```

Comment: Make sure you mark this as accepted if you've solved the problem.